# Extension of compressed parquet file in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet, spark2.4.4

In my Spark job, I write a compressed parquet file like this:

```
df
  .repartition(numberOutputFiles)
  .write
  .option("compression","gzip")
  .mode(saveMode)
  .parquet(avroPath)
```

Then, my files has this extension : file_name **.gz.parquet**

How can I have **".parquet.gz"** ?

Comment: Can you show us what value `avroPath` has?  In my case (on Spark 2.4.5 using `spark-shell`) when I use the same command as you I just get the exact filename I specify. So if I have `orangeJuice` instead of your `avroPath`, I will get `orangeJuice` as file name. If I choose `orangeJuice.parquet.gz`, I get that file name.

Comment: It is something like "/my/path/partition_id=xxxxx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can. File extension is hardcoded in [`ParquetWrite.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/v2/parquet/ParquetWrite.scala#L113) as concatenation of codec's extension and ".parquet", in that order:

```
  :
    override def getFileExtension(context: TaskAttemptContext): String = {
      CodecConfig.from(context).getCodec.getExtension + ".parquet"
    }
  :
```

So, unless you want to change the source and compile your own Spark version, or open a JIRA request against Spark... ;))